# Job alerts page not found

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

If I go from the page where I can see the newsletters I'm subscribed to to the page for job alerts I get a Page not Found

The url I get send to is `https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/job-alerts?`

If I go from a different page to "Job Alerts" it does give me the correct url, eg. from "Edit Profile" to "Job Alerts" it sends me to `https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/job-alerts/1498624`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the heads up; fix is now built out to prod.